# Excel IF AND OR statement syntax issue

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I’m hoping someone can help me with getting the correct syntax for this formula.

=if(and(panel_quantity>0),OR(c1:z1)<>””),”yes”,”no”)

Below is an explanation For what I want the formula to achieve.

If Panel_Quantity is greater than zero AND if and any of the cells in the range of C1:Z1 contains any text/value/formula then cell value is “yes”, otherwise “no”.

Thanks.

Comment: Not at my pc now but I don't think you need the or connection, your english version of the statement doesn't have an or so why should the implementation

Comment: the parenthesis after`""` , delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=if(and(panel_quantity>0, counta(c1:z1) > 0),"yes","no")
```